# Find disjoint set irrespective of case of the strings

Tags: java, collections, set

I am using [Collection.disjoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) to find the disjoint set of two string collections `c1, c2.` But it does not ignore cases, for example - string `str` is different than `Str`.

```
return Collections.disjoint(c1, c2);
```

Can I find the disjoint of both collections ignoring their cases without using a for loop?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: nooooooooooo.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why haven't you guys added something like that to Guava? It seems you could overload the `union` or `difference` methods of `Sets` to take a `Comparator` of sorts.

Comment: It's awkward to do efficiently in a generic way, it's not actually as common a need as you might think, and it tends to be more readable and less surprising done "the normal way."  Additionally, our existing `union` and `difference` methods return views, not copies, it's impossible to do this efficiently in a view, and breaking that precedent would be weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely insist that no `for` loop is used, you can always find the disjoint between two `Collection`s of lowercased `String`s. Using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it should be something like:

```
package ru.zombator.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;

public final class DisjointIgnoreCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<String> coll1 = Arrays.asList("donald", "Duck");
        Collection<String> coll2 = Arrays.asList("DONALd", "Donut");
        Collection<String> coll3 = Arrays.asList("Homer", "DONUT");
        Collection<String> coll4 = Arrays.asList("DONALD", "duck");

        // will all print false
        System.out.println(disjointIgnoreCase(coll1, coll2));
        System.out.println(disjointIgnoreCase(coll2, coll3));
        System.out.println(disjointIgnoreCase(coll1, coll4));

        // will print true (no common elements)
        System.out.println(disjointIgnoreCase(coll1, coll3));
    }       

    private static boolean disjointIgnoreCase(Collection<String> coll1, Collection<String> coll2) {
        return Collections.disjoint(lowercased(coll1), lowercased(coll2));
    }       

    private static Collection<String> lowercased(Collection<String> coll) {
        return Collections2.transform(coll, new Function<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(String input) {
                return input.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to convert the values of both lists to lowercase. Creating new lists is not needed as the function is applied to the values the value references are the same - inplace change.

```
c1.stream().map(s -> s.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
c2.stream().map(s -> s.toLowerCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.disjoint(c1, c2);
```

One cannot put directly the mapping in the disjoint because multiple levels of processing is not allowed here.